# How do you build a function that solves the same task as the join() array method only using for loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, methods

```
const array = [
 "My",
 "teacher",
 "is",
 "teaching",
 "me",
 "FOR",
 "loops",
 "and",
 "functions",
 "!"
];

function joinToString(array, separator) {
  let output = "";
  for (let ele of array) {
    if () {
    }
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is take the separator(" ") and add it to the end of each element(strings) of the array. I am only trying to use the for loop and use the push method for the function.

Comment: Join produces a string. Why are you pushing to a new array when you want a string? Build a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there.

If you can't use join, you can use string concatenation, and in your return just apply a slice so the extra separator at the end is removed.

Also, your array has semicolons, but they should be commas.

```js
const array = [
 "Devslopes",
 "is",
 "teaching",
 "me",
 "FOR",
 "loops",
 "and",
 "functions",
 "!"
];

const separator = " ";

function joinToString(array, separator) {
 let output = "";
 
 for (let ele of array) {
  output += ele + separator;
 }
 return output.slice(0, -1);
}

console.log(joinToString(array, separator))
```

Comment: will this work for a different separator? space seems to be only an example

Comment: Try changing the separator and find out? @codingStarter

Comment: @Andy i didnt mean to the general idea, trim will only remove spaces at the end of the word, using a different separator wont give the desired result

Comment: @codingStarter, I updated my answer with a simple solution, slice. It removes the last character no matter what.

Comment: @imvain2 still worng, because separator might be longer than one char, i thing you need to change the loop, and the question was to only use loop, so i am not sure you can use trim or slice

Answer (score 3):

It might be less pretty, but it is still simple:

```
function joinToString(array, separator) {
 let result = "";
 for (let i = 0; i< array.length -1 ;i++) {
  result += array[i] + separator;
 } 
 return result + array[array.length-1];
}
```

it just manually add the last value of the array

Comment: You could just `return result + array[array.length-1];` to avoid the last assignment.

Comment: Just a note since you mentioned prettiness ;)